# Chrome search terms : Sit, Stay, Good Boy

Tags: google-chrome

I love chrome, but I want my search term to stay in the CTRL-F search box as I browse different pages.

Is this possible?

Comment: +1 ... not so much because of the question, but because of the title :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean you want to keep the search box open on other tabs right, since the search term itself is kept if you press CTRL+F on other tabs (at least in my version it does - I use 4.0.249.89)

Google guys say they don't want to implement this feature:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7249

Comment: What about for the _same_ tab? I want to search all 0...n webpages of a web article for the same search term, but when I click a link, CTRL-F empties and disappears.